# Azure DevOps (TFS) | create SSH service connection automatically to Linux Server

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

Does anyone has PowerShell script that create SSH service connection to Linux server with Grant access permission to all pipelines?

Alternatively, if you can provide clear procedure of TFS CLIs to create one service connection will be helpful as well or if you can share example of service-endpoint-configuration file to Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a script to call the REAT API ([Endpoints - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for Azure DevOps Services) to create the service connection. For on-premiers Azure DevOps server : [Endpoints - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

And then call the REST API to grant the pipeline permissions for the endpoint.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{Project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinePermissions/endpoint/{endpointID}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Below PowerShell script for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}", #Azure DevOps services organization or on-premiers Azure DevOps Server Collection URL
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
# Set your parameters and SSH service connection name

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
    {
        "administratorsGroup": null,
        "authorization": {
            "scheme": "UsernamePassword",
            "parameters": {
                "username": "test",
                "password": "test"
            }
        },
        "createdBy": null,
        "data": {
            "Host": "172.17.16.69",
            "Port": "22",
            "PrivateKey": "xxxx"
        },
        "description": "SSH Test6",
        "groupScopeId": null,
        "name": "SSH Test6",
        "operationStatus": null,
        "readersGroup": null,
        "serviceEndpointProjectReferences": [
            {
                "description": "SSH Test",
                "name": "SSH Test",
                "projectReference": {
                    "id": "901f7f54-f0b1-40cb-8b6c-f82d590b0838",
                    "name": "Test0924"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ssh",
        "url": "",
        "isShared": false,
        "owner": "library"
    }
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody


# Create service connection 
$sshurl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.1-preview.2" 
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $sshurl -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$endpointid = $result.id

#Grant pipeline permissions

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
    {
        "resource": {
            "id": "$endpointid",
            "type": "endpoint",
            "name": ""
        },
        "pipelines": [],
        "allPipelines": {
            "authorized": true,
            "authorizedBy": null,
            "authorizedOn": null
        }
    }
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody
 
$permissionurl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/pipelines/pipelinePermissions/endpoint/$($endpointid)?api-version=5.1-preview.1" 
Write-Host "permissionurl:"$permission
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $permissionurl -Method PATCH -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```